# what is the usage of the setgid bit on a server?

Tags: linux, unix, acl, bit

good evening.

After some investigation on the server - (spending many many hours with the security): I have a serious question: what is the usage of the SETGID bit on a server!?

many thanks for some help!

zero

whats the difference

```
drwxrwxrwx 
drwxr-s---
```

i mean the SETGID bit!?

```
drwxrwxrwx 
drwxr-s--- 
drwxr-xr-x  17 vhost vhost 
      ^ Here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

**special question:** can i switch it on / of with filezilla

Comment: yes i mean  setgit! BTW - can i do some settings on setgit with filezilla!? is this possible? Hmmm - or should i use dolphin.(/i know that dolphin can work on setgit

Comment: Try again.  You keep writing "setgit".  Do you mean "setgid"?  If so, this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) will probably help.  If not, please explain what you mean by "setgit".

Comment: Setting the setgid bit on existing subdirectories must be done manually, with a command such as the following:

`[root@foo]# find /path/to/directory -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`

Comment: Keith - can i do the settting of the setgit-bit with filezilla!?

Comment: I'm not aware that filezilla can set something called a "setgit" bit, because as far as I know there is no such thing as a "setgit" bit.  There might be, and if there is you need to tell us what it is.  Filezilla probably can set the "setgid" bit.  After several people have asked you whether you mean "setgid" or "setgit", you haven't given a clear answer.  (I know the question now says "SETGID", but that's because somebody else edited it for you.)  **Do you mean "setgid"??**

Answer (score 3):

When the setgid bit is set on a directory, all files (or directories) created in that directory will belong to the group that owns the directory, even if the effective GID of the process that creates the file is different.  It can be useful to ensure that a team of people can edit the files in the directory because they all belong to the same group, and all the files in the directory belong to the group.  You can override the default group with an explicit `chgrp` command.

On MacOS X, all directories behave as if the setgid bit is set.